# What does "Unique Equipped" mean?

Tags: diablo-iii

This appears to show on all Legendary (brown/tan) items. I can't find any info on it, and it doesn't appear to be because the item is class-specific (as my other class-specific items don't have the tag). A friend says this means the item is unusable by other characters once the item is equipped the first time. Is this true? What does "Unique Equipped" mean?

[image: Unique Equipped on Legendary item]

Comment: I can confirm that Legendaries can be equipped by one person then by another, as I have done this as we were all gawking at how cool it looked on our characters.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It means you can only equip one of the item in question. This is mainly relevant for rings and weapons, but is probably just automatically applied to other legendaries.

Comment: Does this still apply if I get two differently named rings, such as one being a Manald Heal and the other a Puzzle Ring?

Comment: @xiath In a sense it still applies, but that doesn't prevent you from equipping both: if you have two different unique rings, you can still only equip one of each.

Answer (score 3):

Usually unique equipped means that only one of the items may be equipped at the same time.

E.g. if you had 2 of the same ring and it was unique equipped you would only be able to wear one of them.

But as this is a spirit stone which is equipped in the head slot it doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if the one 'Unique-Equipped item w/ the same name' rule really applies...
I have two rings both named Stolen Ring, both Unique-Equipped but with different stats, both equipped on my character.

Comment: I wonder if one of your Stolen Rings is "Legacy" (pre 1.0.4) and the other is not and thus able to bypass the unique equipped restriction.

Answer (score 1):

In World of Warcraft, "Unique-equipped" means that you can only wear one of that item at a time. In Diablo 3, this attribute could only possibly have a purpose on rings or gems, though it may apply to equipping both yourself and a follower with the same item (but I doubt it). I assume that, even though the attribute means nothing on this helmet, "Unique" or "Unique-equipped" is an attribute that all legendary items share for the sake of consistency.

Answer (score 0):

This aparently applies to 1 hand weapons also, as I just bought a second "Crystal Fist" just to find out I can not equip it in my other hand. 
I would be interested in knowing if I could use a set item such as "Shenlong's Relentless Assault" while having the "Crystal Fist" equiped. If not then I will just have to keep an eye out for a rare item with similar attribute for my other hand.

Comment: You can equip any combination of Unique Equipped items as long as they are not the same item. For your example, Shenlong's Relentless Assault and Crystal Fist can both be equipped. This is because they are not the same item.