# Can you wear/use multiple legendary items of the same type?

Tags: diablo-iii

Can you wear/use multiple legendary items of the same type?

I bought a legendary ring for argument sake call it the ring of power, now when I bought another ring of power I was unable to equip both of them at the same. Now if I get if I get a different legendary ring called the ring of wisdom. Will I be able to wear both legendary rings at the same time if they are different?

Do the same rules apply to dual wielding?

If the above rules apply to rings that you can't wear two legendary rings. Can you equip a legendary weapon and shield?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can equip as many Legendaries as you want in whatever slots you have available.

The exception is that you cannot equip **more than one** of a *specific* legendary labelled as [**Unique-Equipped**](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/67949/what-does-unique-equipped-mean). Note, this does not mean you cannot equip two Legendaries of the same *item type* or *slot type*, merely that you cannot equip two that have *the exact same name* unless one is a [legacy](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/81331/how-can-i-tell-the-difference-between-old-and-new-legendaries) item and the other is not.  A legacy item will show differently in auction house searches but not in your inventory.