# How can I tell the difference between old and new Legendaries?

Tags: diablo-iii

In patch 1.0.4, lots of Legendary/Set items received an upgrade. However, this upgrade was not applied to existing items.  In the Auction House, these items are differentiated between **when searching** by adding `[LEGACY]` to the end of the legendary name and new Set items have new names altogether.  However, the actual item descriptions don't appear to have anything to distinguish them.

Is there any way to tell the difference between a 1.0.3 Legendary and a 1.0.4+ Legendary?  This is most crucial when trading unidentified items.

Comment: Does it suck? Legacy legendary.

Comment: @Resorath - Can't tell if it sucks when it's unidentified.

Comment: Great question, I wasn't aware of this affecting unidentified legendaries.  This would be more than a little concerning, although obviously a workaround would be only buying identified legendaries. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no definitive way to distinguish between unidentified legendaries pre or post 1.04.  If it is level 63, it is likely to be a new one, but not in all cases.

In many cases, there is no easy way to tell whether even an identified legendary is old or new.  Some new legendaries (and all new sets) have new names, so in those cases, there will be no confusion.

For the remainder of the items, it may be discernable if you compare the affixes with an old iteration of the item.  If the legendary has a 'special power', it's new.  If it has great damage, it's very likely new.  In all other cases, it is either old, or it is a new one with a mediocre stat roll.

Answer (score 5):

The item level of the object might point that it is the 1.0.4 legendary :

`Legendary items used to cap out at ilvl 62, making it near impossible to find a weapon that had strong DPS. No more. We’ve promoted a LOT of the new Legendaries so that they will roll at ilvl 63`

Source is [here](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/blog/6923457/)

So if you see a legendary with ilvl 63 it is one of those new legendaries.

Answer (score 1):

To tell the difference, go to the AH, go to sell, and right click the questionable item and hit "Search for similar" And it will either search legacy, or non legacy. It it searches non legacy it is non legacy. If it searches for a legacy... it's a legacy.

Comment: So, AH reveals accidentally what the item is, without identifying it? This must be a severe bug..

Comment: Yeah, the question is particularly concerned with unidentified Legendaries, which I don't think you can do anything with on the AH, including searching for similars.

Comment: I am more concerned with identifying them when other people are trying to trade them to me

Answer (score 0):

> To distinguish these items from one another, new Legendary items will
>   have slightly different names and appearances from those dropped or
>   created prior to 1.0.4.

[Source (Patch 1.0.4 notes)](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/blog/7029347/Patch_104_Now_Live-8_21_2012)

For unidentified legendary items, you will have to pay special attention to the appearance.

Comment: The new Griswald's Masterpiece has the *exact* same name as the old one.

Comment: I believe the new names are only applicable for the set items.  Non-set legendaries all have the same name.

Comment: @OrigamiRobot: I am afraid this is all the info I have. Maybe the OP from Blizzard meant "different names and/or appearances"... =/ bwarner: The paragraph I took the info from is supposed to refer too all legendaries, not just to set items.

Comment: You can see in their preview screenshots that the new ones have the same name.  A quick look at the auction house right now verifies that as well.